# Function prepend() jquery hover and counter click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with `prepend()` because if I "copy" my div and if click on counter the count change in whole divs the same is with hover. Is this possible change number count and hover only in clicked or hovered div?

Thank you for help and time:)

HTML

```
<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="count">My Counter</div>
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="hover"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
<button class=AddDiv>AddDiv</button>
```

And javascript

```
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="count">My Counter</div><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>'));
});
var count = 0;
$(".count").click(function() {
    count++;
    $(".count").html(+count);
});

$(".background").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(".hover").fadeIn(500);
});
$(".hover").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(".hover").fadeOut(200);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mpd075s8/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are creating dynamic id for each `prepend`. And by sending that div id to the javascript function and using same count logic as [@Zakaria Acharki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4281779/zakaria-acharki) used to maintain count value.

```js
var divNumber = 1;
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="count" id="div'+divNumber+'" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>'));
  divNumber++;
});

function makeCount(id){
  var count = parseInt( $("#"+id).text());
  if( isNaN(count) ){
    count = 1; //For the first click
  }else{
    count++;
  }

  $("#"+id).text(count);
}

$(".background").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(".hover").fadeIn(500);
});
$(".hover").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(".hover").fadeOut(200);
});
```

```css
.Wrap
{
  width:650px;
  height:800px;
}
.container
{
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.AddDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}
.count
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-50px;
  margin-top:-50px;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  cursor:pointer;  
}
.background
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:green;
  position:absolute;
  left:170px;
  top:10px;
}
.hover
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1001;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="count" id="div0" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div>
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="hover"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
<button class=AddDiv>AddDiv</button>
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your advice, but I must ask you for next help with hover in this divs, maybe you know why when I hover on class="background" hovered are all new divs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes sure, use the current clicked element object `$(this)` :

```
$(this).html(+count);
```

Instead of :

```
$(".count").html(+count);
```

And use event delegation `on()` to attach click event to the new elements added dynamically to the DOM :

```
$("body").on('click',".count",function() {
     count++;
     $(this).html(+count);
});
```

To increment count separatelly for every div you should get the current count then add 1 to it, like :

```
$("body").on('click',".count",function() {
  var count = parseInt( $(this).text() );

  if( isNaN(count) ){
    count = 1; //For the first click
  }else{
    count++;
  }

  $(this).text(count);
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function(){
  $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="count">My Counter</div><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>'));

});


$("body").on('click',".count",function() {
  var count = parseInt( $(this).text() );

  if( isNaN(count) ){
    count = 1; //For the first click
  }else{
    count++;
  }

  $(this).text(count);
});

$(".background").on("mouseover", function () {
  $(".hover").fadeIn(500);
});
$(".hover").on("mouseout", function () {
  $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="count"> Click Me
    </div>
    <div class="background">
    </div>
    <div class="hover">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
<button class=AddDiv>AddDiv</button>
```

Comment: but look if you click ones it will be "1" but if click another div will be "2" not 1, but would like that every div will be apart count, but of course thank you very much this more than I had :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.insertBefore()` function:

check: https://jsfiddle.net/mpqtrjzx/

```
$( '<div class="container"><div class="count">My Counter</div><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>' ).insertBefore( ".container:first" );
```